# 90s Syfy movie about a red virus that takes over the Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, virus, sy-fy

I remember as a kid (mid-90s), a movie was playing on the Syfy channel. From what I remember, a Caucasian guy and lady were in a plane about to take off from the runway while a red goo-like virus was taking over the surface of the Earth.

If anyone has played *Machine Head* on the PlayStation, the red goo-like virus looked exactly the same as the red virus in the game.

Comment: The red weed is a feature of The War of The World's, but there are non listed for mid 90s. https://m.imdb.com/list/ls058900268/

Comment: Could this be "The Langoliers" television mini series, based on Stephen King's novella of the same name?

Answer (score 3):

Partial match: *Invasion from Inner Earth* (1974).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071666/plotsummary/?ref_=tt_ov_pl):

> A group of young pilots in a remote region of the Canadian wilderness begin to hear strange reports over their radios about **planes crashing**, cars stalling and **a deadly plague which has gripped the planet**. It becomes clear that earth is in the midst of an invasion. The group of pilots decide to barracade themselves in a cabin deep in the woods and wait for their impending doom.

Several reviews mention a plane crashing, [for instance](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw0136184/):

> Let's see, cut every so often to the frantic scene of a city being menaced by colored smoke and then cut back to the cabin people who need a radio so they can call home and then a red light shows up and then something happens. **Every time a red light shows up, it's bad. I can tell you that much. Beware of those red lights.** The apparently do something.
>
> **Someone escapes in an airplane and they might have been killed but let's just forget about them since the movie never really explains it.** Someone is shined upon with a red light in the woodshed. The people in the city are running in circles. There's colored smoke! Run people! Run!

Matches:

- Red thingy taking other the world
- From the official summary it's supposedly a virus, although the reviews explain that this is widely handwaved
- Could have been aired in the 90s

Not a match:

- The red thingy is more smoke than goo
- The very little available footage from this movie makes the comparison with *Machine Head* hard

---

Remembered by having previously identified it (earlier today!) for [1980s sci-fi horror movie about a red mist that would kill people](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/282809/). I stumbled upon the current question by browsing unanswered stuff, and thought the movie might be a good candidate here as well.